# I'm looking for a word that describes a thing that looks like another thing (both inanimate). Is there one…?

Tags: greek

I thought up *pragmamorphism* but somebody beat me to the punch with an anthropocentric definition that I was trying to avoid. I’ve looked at a couple of other Ancient Greek word constructs, but outside of mineralogy, they don’t make sense. Does the word I’m searching for exist?

For example, ‘The tapioca looked like frogspawn with perfect _ _ _ _’.

Comment: Metaphorically: Twin, Clone, Doppleganger? Lookalike? Dupe?

Comment: Perhaps a fake? Are you asking for a word with Greek roots?

Comment: I’m looking for an overarching, generic term. I did think the Ancient Greek would be the way to go, but perhaps it isn’t. I’m looking for a term that describes clouds looking like mashed potato, I suppose!

Comment: This is an English Language forum, not Greek. In looking for a single word, you should give an example sentence that includes enough context.

Comment: This would be a word like anthropomorphism which, while it has its origins in Ancient Greek, forms part of current English usage.

Comment: Something like:  That cloud looks like a dragon eating a palm tree in a *Rorschach-esque* kind of a way.

Comment: Yes. And context sentence added to my main question.

Comment: What are you trying to express that the sentence *The tapioca looked just like frogspawn* doesn't express?

Comment: "similarity" can fit into the blank. But I'm not sure what it adds.

Comment: "Dead ringer" is a perfect idiom to what you have in mind, although it is not a single word and you'd have to reword the sentence.

Answer (score -1):

> The tapioca looked like frogspawn with perfect **resemblance**.

which can perhaps be shortened to:

> The tapioca bore a **perfect resemblance** to frogspawn.

**resemblance** (n.)

> The state of resembling or being alike. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/resemblance?locale=en)

> The quality or state of resembling [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resemblance)

---

> But it was held by the Judges, that as those parts of the forged
> stamp, which were visible, **bore a perfect resemblance** to the same
> parts of the genuine stamp, and that the whole was so artfully
> contrived as to be likely to deceive the eye of every common observer,
> there was a sufficient **resemblance** to shew that a false making was
> intended; ... [Edward E. Deacon; *A Digest of the Criminal Law of
> England*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Digest_of_the_Criminal_Law_of_England/p7ZCAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22bore%20a%20perfect%20resemblance%20to%22&pg=PA1433&printsec=frontcover) (1831)

> The **resemblance was uncanny**. This man was the spitting image of
> the donkey-headed companion he had traveled with on a previous
> adventure. [James W. Greenhalge; *The Fourth Jewel of Earth*, p.210](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Fourth_Jewel_of_Earth/W8-DbuzhWm4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=the%20resemblance%20is%20uncanny&pg=PA210&printsec=frontcover) (2008)

> The median of the ratios.... is an important measure of
> **resemblance**. When it is 0, it means no greater **resemblance** than one of the group bears to another taken at rendom. When it is 1.00 it
> means a **perfect resemblance or identity.** [Edward L. Thorndike;
> Educational Psychology](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Educational_Psychology_Mental_work_and_f/eLIgAlp90xkC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=perfect%20resemblance&pg=PA231&printsec=frontcover) (1923)

> "At the risk of destroying an illusion very dear to the public, I
> venture to state that no portrait exists or has existed which is a
> **perfect resemblance**—that is, one which will be acknowledged by everybody as a **perfect resemblance.** The face of a person is just
> as changeable as his emotions. This alone excludes the possibility of
> an absolute and universally acknowledged **resemblance**...." [An anonymous painter; *American
> Photography*, Vol. 9, p.120](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Photography/8oVRVHxnDQ8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=perfect%20resemblance&pg=PA120&printsec=frontcover) (1915)

> If one continues the idea of phenotypic canalization, monozygotic
> twins are therefore in every way entangled. This may explain their
> **almost perfect resemblance**, throughout their life and up to later ages, including for twins raised separately. [Jean-Pierre Hugot; *A
> Probabalistic Model of the Genotype/Phenotype Relationship*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_Probabilistic_Model_of_the_Genotype_Ph/I-5gDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=perfect%20resemblance&pg=PA53&printsec=frontcover) (2018)

Comment: Yes but only the shortened form "The tapioca bore a perfect resemblance to frogspawn" really works. Further shortening, to "the tapioca resembled frogspawn" might be better but anything "… with perfect resemblance" sounds like a foreign grammar text. Then, what difference does either thing being inanimate make, and how would that apply to frogspawn?